# Sorting a counter (and extracting the most common values)

Tags: julia

[DataStructures.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl) provides a great set of tools, one of which is a [counter](https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl#accumulators-and-counters). The corresponding Python object, `Counter` provides a `most_common` method. How would this be implemented in Julia?

Answer (score 3):

The heavy lifting can be done by `select!`. The following should reproduce the behavior of `most_common` in Python:

```
using DataStructures

most_common(c::Accumulator)    = most_common(c, length(c))
most_common(c::Accumulator, k) = select!(collect(c), 1:k, by=kv->kv[2], rev=true)
```

There will be a performance hit until Julia gains the ability to specialize on the function argument `by=kv->kv[2]` (which is planned), and until indexing is made to returns view (which is also planned), it will perform a needless copy to create an output vector of the right length. But as long as it is not performance critical, the above should work fine.

The performance problems could of course be handled with a more careful, low-level implementation. I don't know of an existing function for this, but it could be a worthwhile addition to DataStructures.jl or Julia itself. It would make sense also for associative collections that are not counters or accumulators, but should probably be named something else then.

Answer (score 0):

To update this question, I'm using Julia v1.2.1 and there is no `select!` afaik.

Here is a slight modification to @Toivo's implementation I used:

```
using DataStructures

most_common(c::Accumulator) = most_common(c, length(c))
most_common(c::Accumulator, k) = sort(collect(c), by=kv->kv[2], rev=true)[1:k]
```

This returns an `::Array{Pair{String,Int}},1` with `k` members which is similar to Python `Counter.most_common(k)` which returns a list of tuple pair up to `k`.

**Example:**

Find the ten most common words in Hamlet, using Python `Counter` and Julia `DataStructures.counter`.

Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('hamlet.txt').read().lower())
>>> Counter(words).most_common(10)
[('the', 1143), ('and', 966), ('to', 762), ('of', 669), ('i', 631),
 ('you', 554),  ('a', 546), ('my', 514), ('hamlet', 471), ('in', 451)]
```

Julia:

```
> import DataStructures: counter
> open("hamlet.txt") do f
>     words = matchall(r"\w+", read(f, String))
>     counter(words)|> most_common
> end
10-element Array{Pair{Any,Int64},1}:
"the" => 1143
"and" => 966
"to" => 762
 ...
```

I'm not experienced enough to comment about the efficiency, but would love to hear from the experts.